# Take an action from params, only first time link is visited - in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, object, parameters

I'm looking to get the params of a URL, and do something with it. In this case, I want to add a new Gift Conversion to the user's account, if that link is displayed in a browser. However, I only want this to happen the first time someone visits this link. Is there a way to make sure this action only happens once? Thanks everyone for your help!

```
if params[:secret_user_id].present?
  @referral_card_signup = User.find(params[:secret_user_id])
  @referral = @referral_card_signup.gift_conversions
  1.times{@referral << GiftConversion.new}
end
```

Comment: What is the GiftConversion model like?  Why not just add a boolean field called `received?` that gets switched to `true` when the user clicks the link

Comment: Or alternatively You can blank his secret_user_id.

Comment: Forgive me... I'm very new at ruby (if you couldn't tell). How would I 'blank' his secret_user_id, after receiving params from it?